# Using read_shp() to generate networkx.DiGraph from point and line shapefiles

Tags: python, networkx

I tried to use the Python module networkx and specifically the read-shp () to ensure the transformation of a graph to a file sharpe but I always find this error noting that this is the first time I developed Python (level zero).

```
       >>> import networkx as nx

       >>>G=nx.DiGraph()

       >>> G=nx.read_shp('/home/test.shp')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError:
> 'module' object has no attribute 'read_shp'

Comment: Do you still have this issue? if you are, try with a different line or point shapefile (different producer) and see how it works out for you